# Is Electric Muscle Stimulation (EMS) treatment beneficial for shoulder injury?

Tags: muscle, treatment-options, shoulder

Due to a fall (during training) on my left shoulder, about 6 months ago, I've been experiencing mild to severe pain in my left shoulder. Pressing the [AC joint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acromioclavicular_joint) hurts and upward movements tend to increase the pain. Even after weeks of slight to no training, the pain comes back fast after light boxing. I've been placing a [EMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_muscle_stimulation) device daily, for about a week now. Will I benefit by this or not? Next to that, I take Brufen to reduce inflammation and pain.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Have you seen a doctor? AC joint injuries, while not uncommon, can cause extensive damage, which often worsens over time. X-rays and/or other tests are vital for early and accurate diagnosis, and to put a treatment plan in place. A period of immobility may be required, and any boxing at all may be making it worse. While I'd like to help you, my personal opinion is that you should seek medical care. Someone here may disagree with me, though, and offer some good advice. I hope you feel better soon!

Comment: @Sue, thanks for the response! Well, i have some sort of scans planned within 2 weeks, followed with a consultation. So i'll probably will have the final verdict then :/ Hopefully not too bad!

Comment: Excellent, I'm glad to hear that. Also, if you're interested in some general information about EMS, take a look at [this](http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1160/difference-between-tens-and-ems-electro-stimulation/1172#1172) question. Keep us posted!

Comment: @Sue, the doctor's examination stated: severe arthritis on the AC-joint. Pain can be suppressed with anti-inflamation and painkillers, or even cortisone injections. In the long run, it could be advised to get the joint removed. But for now on, I can carefully restart training and do more stability exercises.

Comment: @c0s1n3, steroid injections weaken the tissues around the injection (tendons, ligaments), so repeated injections increase the risk of tendon rupture. Also, I believe arthritis that resulted from an injury, can heal optimally with rest, not with training.

Comment: @Jan , thanks for the response! Meanwhile the shoulder injury healed perfectly, without the need of steroid injections!